# TFS 2013 nUnit integration and different AppDomain for each test assembly

Tags: c#, nunit, tfsbuild

I have a problem running some tests in my solution.
Because of some messes around in my projects which I cannot fix I need to run each test assembly (or test) in a different AppDomain.
I know it can be done with nUnit executable or .nUnit file as written in the official documentation (http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=assemblyIsolation&r=2.6.3) but I cannot integrate it in the build.

Is it possible to add some similar option in tfs 2013 build process (ie. .runsettings file)?
Has anybody had a similar problem and found a solution or a workaround?

Thanks in advance,

Andrea.

Answer (score 0):

I think you will need create many build/deploys... But... The Unit Test target is run all tests together, you have need refactoring your code soon!